# Enable Android System Webview on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to embed a webview into an Android app based on Android 5.1.1.
Installed Android System WebView(beta) from the PlayStore, version 65.0.3325.114 but somehow when I try some URL, it doesn't seem to work well with JS ES6. 
Checking nginx logs, show Chrome/39.0.0.0 so I suspect my app's WebView is still loading the built in WebView and not the Android System WebView. 
Am I missing something or is there any way to enable from developer options?
Just found googling an option to enable but only for Android M, not present in 5.1.1.

Thanx!

Comment: Same issue here as I'm running my app on a DJI Crystal Sky which keeps loading the outdated system browser.

Comment: Hey TomDK, unfortunately I couldn't find a workaround. Stuck with the old WebView, guess the only way is changing the older hardware :(

Comment: It's so unfortunate that Google is this arrogant with that issue.

My problem is that I'm developing Android Apps for DJI's industrial Drone's which are shipped with the DJI Crystal Sky (that tablet alone is nearly 1000$) and apart from the Android Version, a rather good device. So changing hardware is sadly not an popular option with the users of my software :(

Need to keep looking.

Comment: You are in an interesting project! Pls let me know if you find a workaround.